# Logic app until loop breaks after HTTP call receives 400

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[image]

Under change limits I have count 8 and timeout as PT30M. The problem is that I would like to loop eight times and try that HTTP call until I receive status code 200. However, my loop breaks after the first call if the HTTP request received 400. What should I add in the loop to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a variable that stores the status code.

[image]

Then use the `Set variable` in the `Until` action to assign the status code returned by the `Http` action to the variable.

[image]

You need to configure [configure run after](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#customize-run-after-behavior) to make your `Azure logic app` still run after the `Http` action fails.

[image]

[image]